# Hide all open windows on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window-management

Is it possible to have a button on the side bar to hide every open window on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a button to execute `wmctrl -k on` to get the same effect.

I already have such a thing on 12.04 LTS in my taskbar ( classic desktop, no side-bar ).

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard shortcut is always better and faster than a GUI approach.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will minimize all the windows on Ubuntu.

Alternatively, you can try the *hot corner* feature of [Unity Tweak Tool](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool), which is a GUI approach, but still very fast.

Comment: Super + D (Windows key + D), leaving out the "Ctrl" key, seems to do the same (tried on Ubuntu 18.04.02).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an option for the [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) desktop environment. You can select an additional entry for your desktop panel which is called **'Show desktop'** and it will show or hide all windows when clicked on.

This has been available for gnome-like desktop environments since a couple of years so it should work for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as well.

See this screenshot:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto "Settings" > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Navigation" and set an appropriate shortcut for "Hide all normal windows".

**Note:** I'm using Pop OS 20.10

[image]